# Stop ## quartz_off_screen showing in HTML report

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

My R Markdown files contain code to save PDF files e.g.

```
pdf(paste0("plots/filtering/", exp_name, "_umap.pdf"))
walk(list(p4, p5, p6, p7), print)  
dev.off()
```

When I knit to HTML, I get the following printed as part of the HTML.

```
## quartz_off_screen  
##                 2
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I already have the `knitr` chunk options `message` and `warning` set to `FALSE`.

Best wishes,

Lucy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the the call to `dev.off` with `invisible(...)`.

**MWE**

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(vs))) + geom_point()
```


```{r}
pdf("mtcars.pdf")
walk(list(p1, p2), print)
invisible(dev.off())
```
````

Comment: No need to call `capture.output()`. Simply `invisible(dev.off())` should work.